# ImportError: No module named catkin_pkg.packages on indigo?

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when i use python -v it returns Python 2.7.11 :: Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229670/importerror:-no-module-named-catkin_pkg.packages-on-indigo?/) by [VruShabh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26343/vrushabh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-03-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/56873/problem-with-catkin_make/), hope it helps...

Next time, please provide a proper question as well as some more information, though, ...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1